# Vistas materializadas Firebird

Tags: sql, optimización, firebird, vistas-materializadas

Buenas tardes compañeros, estoy tratando de mejorar el rendimiento de una base de datos en firebird 1.5; he notado que las consultas que hago sobre unas vistas tardan demasiado, y por ahi lei que hay una forma de materializar la vista para mejorar el rendimiento.

he estado buscando pero no me queda muy claro como es el funcionamiento.

firebird 1.5 tiene esa opcion?, o en que version esta implementado esto?

muchas gracias

Comment: Una vez observe que si llamar una vista desde otra vista el sistema se pone supremamente lento, es mejor usar un procedure

Answer (score 0):

Esso de vista materializada no me suena de nada. Par optimizar la vista tienes que poner filtros a la llamada, en where, y procurar que los campos filtrados esten indizados. Si pones la consulta que haces al llamar a la vista quizas se vea mejor el problema.